# Regex matching a very specific Pattern

Tags: regex

I have been trying to create a regex that would accept any of the values (SPAM, FOO, BAR) separated by a | or NONE.
The regex I've been working on does the job, but a problem comes up when a value is entered before those values (See image below for more details).
Any suggestions?
Thank you!

^NONE$|^(?!.*NONE)(?:.*(FOO|BAR|SPAM))*

This is what I am currently working with.

Strings that should pass:

//Should Pass

FOO|BAR|SPAM

FOO

SPAM|BAR

SPAM|FOO

SPAM|FOO|BAR

BAR|FOO

NONE

//Should fail

NONE|FOO

FOO|SPAM|NONE

FOO|NONE|BAR
​
FOO|TEST

FOO_TEST

FOO TEST

FOO|TEST|BAR

FOO_TEST|BAR

​
TEST|FOO

TEST|FOO|BAR

TEST FOO|BAR

TEST_FOO|BAR

​
*TEST is being used as a word that is not in the group

[image]

Comment: Instead of image you should provide details in question like all valid and invalid strings.

Comment: I can do that..Let me edit it

Comment: Try `^(?:(SPAM|FOO|BAR)(?:\|(?!\1)((?1))(?:\|(?!\1|\2)(?1))?)?|NONE)$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jz3lvK/2).

Comment: Your regex does not actually ensure that they're sepearated by a bar; they could be separated by any number of arbitrary characters or nothing. Examples that would pass: `FOOblaBAR`, `FOOBAR`.

Comment: `^(?:NONE|(?:FOO|BAR|SPAM)(?:\|(?:FOO|BAR|SPAM))*)$` should work

Answer (score 2):

This should work: `^NONE$|^(FOO|BAR|SPAM)([|](FOO|BAR|SPAM))*$`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!